# Fastlane getting a 'train_version is no longer a used argument on FastlaneCore' message while uploading to TestFlight

Tags: testflight, fastlane

I'm using Fastlane version 2.125.2.
Using the following lane:

```
lane :beta do
  # increment_build_number
  sync_code_signing(type: "appstore")
  build_app(workspace: "myapp.xcworkspace", scheme: "myapp")
  dsym_name = Time.new.strftime('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M')
  dsym_zip(dsym_path: "./myapp.#{dsym_name}.app.dSYM.zip")
  upload_symbols_to_crashlytics(
    dsym_path: "./myapp.#{dsym_name}.app.dSYM.zip",
    gsp_path: "./myapp/App/GoogleService-Info.plist")
  upload_to_testflight
  slack_success_message
end
```

Fastlane upload the IPA to TestFlight but I'm getting a message at the end of the script:

```
train_version is no longer a used argument on FastlaneCore::BuildWatcher. Please use :app_version instead.
```

This is how it looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a bug in fastlane, please open an issue over at https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues and fill all the information the issue template asks for. Thanks!

Comment: The issue submitted: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14899. I hope it will be fixed soon

Comment: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/14899#issuecomment-503158256